# Hadoop Remote Copying

Tags: java, hadoop

I need to copy some files from hdfs:///user/hdfs/path1 to hdfs:///user/hdfs/path2. I wrote a java code to do the job:-

```
ugi = UserGroupInformation.createRemoteUser("hdfs", AuthMethod.SIMPLE);
System.out.println(ugi.getUserName());
conf = new org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration();
// TODO: Change IP
conf.set("fs.defaultFS", URL);
conf.set("hadoop.job.ugi", user);
conf.set("fs.hdfs.impl", org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.class.getName());
conf.set("fs.file.impl", org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem.class.getName());
// paths = new ArrayList<>();
  fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
```

I am getting all paths for the wild card as

```
fs.globStatus(new Path(regPath));
```

and copy as

```
FileUtil.copy(fs, p, fs, new Path(to + "/" + p.getName()), false, true, conf);
```

However copying is failing with following message whereas globstatus execute successfully

```
WARN  BlockReaderFactory:682 - I/O error constructing remote block reader.
org.apache.hadoop.net.ConnectTimeoutException: 60000 millis timeout while waiting for channel to be ready for connect. ch : java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connection-pending remote=/10.110.80.177:50010]
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:532)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.newConnectedPeer(DFSClient.java:3044)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory.nextTcpPeer(BlockReaderFactory.java:744)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory.getRemoteBlockReaderFromTcp(BlockReaderFactory.java:659)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory.build(BlockReaderFactory.java:327)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.blockSeekTo(DFSInputStream.java:574)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.readWithStrategy(DFSInputStream.java:797)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.read(DFSInputStream.java:844)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:100)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.copyBytes(IOUtils.java:78)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.copyBytes(IOUtils.java:52)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.copyBytes(IOUtils.java:112)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:366)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:338)
```

Note that I am running code remotely over Internet using port forwarding. I.e.

192.168.1.10[JAVA API] ---> 154.23.56.116:8082[Name Node Public I/P]======10.1.3.4:8082[Name Node private IP]

I guess following is the reason:-

1. Query is made to namenode for globStatus which is successfully executed by the name node
2. Copying command is passed to namenode which will return 10.110.80.177:50010 for other data nodes address on other machines, and then Java IP will try to pass the copy commands to these data nodes, since they are not exported to outside world I got this error!

Am I right in this deduction? How to solve the issue? Do I need to create a java server at namenode which will collect copy command and copy the files locally in the cluster.